# python: multiplication of array to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with about 50 columns in it. I need to selectively deselect one or two columns from it and multiply to another array.

What I mean is:

```
df = pandas({'A':numpy.array([,1,4,6,7,8]),'B':numpy.array([4,5,6,7,8]),'C':numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])})
z = numpy.array([5,10])
```

I want to generate dataframe with

```
df['A']*5
df['B']*10
```

or on another instance generate

```
df['A']*5
df['C']*10
```

The name of column to ignore changes based on conditions in the code. So, I want to multiply each element of chosen columns in the dataframe to the array z.

Edit:
replaced word "randomly" with selectively. What I mean is, I get to choose what columns to ignore.

Comment: do you really need to randomly drop a column or there is a condition that determines which column you drop?

Comment: Randomly means based on what the conditions in the code justify, in that sense it is not like random number generation based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do:

```
import random

df[random.sample(df.columns, 2)] * z
```

or if you'd rather keep the ordering:

```
df.drop(random.sample(df.columns, 1), axis = 1) * z
```

Substitute the "random" bit with your own list to achieve "selectiveness" instead of randomness, e.g.:

```
df.drop('A', axis = 1) * z
```

Comment: I modified my question as it was not clear it seems.

Comment: It appears I was modifying my answer at the same time - see the edit.